# appending to table ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having difficulties appending to my table. I keep on appending above the names. Here is the code:

```
  Name  id
  Javi  1
  Tomi  2
```

Well the data keeps on appending at the top. Here is the code:

```
  Lulu  3
  Name  id
  Javi  1
  Tomi  2
```

The code that I am using to append the data is the following. Here is the code:

```
  $(data).prependTo('#feeds:last');
```

How can I append my data correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(data).appendTo('#feeds:last');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.appendTo()`, `prependTo()` adds data to the beginning. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4GZNX/1/)

```
$(data).appendTo('#feeds:last');
```

See [**.appendTo()**](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) documentation.